# Node.js: how can I delay (not sleep) from one line to another to pulse stepper motor in a loop

Tags: node.js, loops, raspberry-pi, delay

I'm controlling a stepper motor with onoff in a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and want to delay between setting pulse high and then low within a loop.

```
for (i=0; i < steps; i++) {
  pinPul.writeSync(1);
  delay here 10 milliseconds
  pinPul.writeSync(0);
  delay another 10 milliseconds
}
```

I don't want to stop the execution of any of the other stuff that's going on in the program during the delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js uses a event loop. And you want to use sync functions that waits.

The default approach in js/node is using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) but it relies on callbacks and cannot be used on a for loop. To fix this you need to use the modern [async/await](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await).

```js
async function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function ledLoop() {
  for (i=0; i < steps; i++) {
    pinPul.writeSync(1);
    await sleep(10);
    pinPul.writeSync(0);
    await sleep(10);
  }
}

ledLoop();
```

Just a comment. 10ms is too fast for the human eye. Change to 1000ms for better testing.

Comment: Awesome!  That's exactly what I was looking for!  Loved the human eye comment!  ;-)